# Find SVD of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, svd

How do I find the singular values?  They somehow show that $\lambda_1 = 27, \lambda_2 = 6, \lambda_3 = 0$. I still can't see how they found them with the equations I made in my solution.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you or the text's solution are based on, but note that you have $$A\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\ -2 & 6\\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}.$$ From here it's easy to find $A$ and the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. I did and it checks out: $\sqrt 6$ and $\sqrt{27}$ are the singular values (and maybe $0$ too, depending on your definition).

Comment: @GitGud You found $A$ by multipling from the right the inverse matrix of $v_1,v_2$?

Comment: @GitGud And btw, thank you very much! It's also an awesome way to solve it, although longer.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost found the SVD of $A$

$$A = \hat{U} \Sigma \hat{V}^T = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & |\\ \frac{2}{\sqrt 6} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & \hat u_3\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & |\\\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \sqrt 3 & 0\\ 0 & \sqrt 6\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix}^T$$

The third column of $\hat U$ has not yet been determined. Since $\hat U$ must be an orthogonal matrix, its columns must be orthonormal. Hence, $\hat u_3$ must be orthogonal to the other two columns of $\hat U$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} |\\ \hat u_3\\ |\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus,

$$\hat u_3 = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\ 0\\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that the eigendecomposition of $A A^T$ is

$$A A^T = \hat{U} \Sigma \hat{V}^T \hat{V} \Sigma^T \hat{U}^T = \hat{U} \Sigma \Sigma^T \hat{U}^T = \hat{U} \begin{bmatrix} 27 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 6 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \hat{U}^T$$

Thus, the three eigenvalues of $A A^T$ are the squares of the two singular values of $A$ and zero.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, but How did you find $\Sigma$ in(Which was my original question I struggled to understand) $$A = \hat{U} \Sigma \hat{V}^T = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & |\\ \frac{2}{\sqrt 6} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & \hat u_3\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & |\\\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \sqrt 3 & 0\\ 0 & \sqrt 6\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix}^T$$ ?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS You found the singular values via $$A \hat v_i = \sigma_i \hat u_i$$Now write the two singular values in the main diagonal of diagonal matrix $\Sigma$.

Comment: I didnt understand how to find the singular values with that equation.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS The singular values are the $\sigma_i$ in the $A \hat v_i = \sigma_i \hat u_i$.